# Sql Query select and fill result with zeros if not exists

Tags: sql, select, zero

Hi guys I need your help.

This is my data in my table called 'table':

```
**key** |    **index**  |   **value**

  a     |    201308     |   23
  b     |    201308     |   9
  a     |    201309     |   5
  c     |    201310     |   3
```

This is my select-try:

```
Select * from Table where index between 201308 and 201310
```

so I need an result like this, to fill index with zero values if date not exist in my table for an key:

```
**key** |    **index**  |   **value**

  a     |    201308     |   23
  a     |    201309     |   5
  a     |    201310     |   0
  b     |    201308     |   9
  b     |    201309     |   0
  b     |    201310     |   0 
  c     |    201308     |   0
  c     |    201309     |   0
  c     |    201310     |   3
```

The best way or result for me should be something like this:

> ```
>  201308    -    201309     -   201310 (Header is not necessary, but helpful if possible) 
> a    23      |    5          |   0 
> b    9       |    0          |   0 
> c    0       |    0          |   0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a "driver" table that creates all possible combinations.  The following query does this using an explicit `cross join`:

```
select driver."key", driver."index", coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from (select k."key", i."index"
      from (select distinct "key" from "table" ) k cross join
           (select distinct "index" from "table") i
     ) driver left outer join
     "table" t 
     on driver."key"= t."key" and driver."index" = t."index"
```

Comment: I don't know why but I don't get the expected result

Comment: What results are you getting?